# Why does SQL Server keep creating the folder “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\” when installing on another driver?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql, database-administration

I specified a different drive wherever applicable during the SQL Server 2017 install. However, the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` keeps getting created. I basically have the expected

```
G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER
G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.SQLDATABASENAME
G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLDATABASENAME
```

and I also have the unwanted:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.SQLDATABASENAME
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLDATABASENAME
```

I know these Those folders are for different SQL Server components:
The MSAS folder is for SQL Server Analysis Services
The MSSQL folder is for the SQL Server Database Service (database engine)

But why is this going to the C drive Program files instead of the directory I specified in the install, is there an easy way to change this? The concern is that I don't want these directories to grow since the OS hard drive is small.

Comment: AS per this document https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 certain paths are fixed

Comment: This directory shouldn't grow much at all, if you have your system DBs, user DBs, and logs all go to other drives.

Comment: @Drifter104 would you write an answer and I'll accept it so this question does not stay opened?